# Created popup window pointing to custom location in Android

Tags: android, view, popup

I'm working on Android application, and I'm using View class to drawing image and drawing objects using canvas. 
I want to show popup balloon pointing to the objects.

Each object has x, y related to the view coordinates.

There is library creating popup message pointing to custom location?

[image]

I will be grateful for the help.